# Extension methods, why: The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties

Tags: c#

I have this very simple code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication3
{
    public interface IInterface1
    {
    }

    public static class Extension1
    {
        public static void DoSomething<TSource>(this TSource obj)
            where TSource : IInterface1
        {
        }
    }

    public class Class1 : IInterface1
    {
    }

    public interface IInterface2
    {
    }

    public static class Extension2
    {
        public static void DoSomething<TSource>(this TSource obj)
            where TSource : IInterface2
        {
        }
    }

    class MainProgram
    {
        void DoStuff()
        {
            var instance1 = new Class1();
            instance1.DoSomething();
        }
    }
}
```

Strangely this line:

```
instance1.DoSomething();
```

gives this error:

> The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties: 'Extension1.DoSomething(TSource)' and 'Extension2.DoSomething(TSource)'

instance1 is an instance of a class which implements Interface1 but not Interface2 and the extension method in Extension1 is defined for objects which implement Interface1. The extension method in Extension2 is defined for objects which implement Interface2. Therefore it does not seem like there can be any issue of ambiguity.

Why is the call ambigious then?

Comment: Generic constraints are not used for overload resolution.

Comment: A duplicate of which question and corresponding answert?

Comment: The duplicate question is [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5918854/generic-extension-method-ambiguity) (although I didn't close your question). You might also find [this](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2009/12/10/constraints-are-not-part-of-the-signature/) helpful.